# UPDATE sql column with value from another column based on a date column

Tags: mysql

From a previous post, I've had the help I needed, but specs have changed a bit and I still need some help.

I'll try to make myself as clear as possible.

I've got two tables, one called Users the other called Users_status.

**Table Users**

```
column 1 : id (pk)
column 2 : status (fk)
```

**Table Users_status**

```
column 1 : user_id (fk)
column 2 : user_status (fk)
column 3 : status_created_at
```

I want to make a cron that verifys that the column 2 of the table Users is up to date of the table  Users_status. The table Users_status may have multiple times the user_id repeating, with the user_status incrementing, like this :

**Table Users_status**

```
    user_id : 1
    user_status : 1
status_created_at : 14/09/14

    user_id : 1
    user_status : 2
status_created_at : 15/09/14

    user_id : 1
    user_status : 3
status_created_at : 16/09/14    

    user_id : 2
    user_status : 1
status_created_at : 14/09/14

    user_id : 2
    user_status : 2
status_created_at : 15/09/14

    user_id : 2
    user_status : 1 // see how user_status came back from 2 to 1
status_created_at : 16/09/14 // most recent status for user_id 2, what I want
```

I want with 1 request, to update the second column of the table Users ( status ) according to the latest status_created_at present in the table Users_status I also want to not update rows that have already the good status ( same status as the table Users_status )

How can this be done? 
When I only needed to update the first table according to the highest ( MAX() ) user_status value, I did it this way (thanks @Gervs) :

```
UPDATE users
JOIN (SELECT
         user_id,
         MAX(status) status
      FROM
         users_status
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) st
ON users.id = st.user_id
SET users.status = st.status
WHERE users.status < st.status
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could give me help on that, I think this is the kind of request that starts to be a little bit too complexe for me :p

Thanks,

Comment: Is status_created_at a date datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a query:

```
UPDATE users
JOIN (SELECT s.user_id,
          s.status
      FROM
          (SELECT
               user_id,
               MAX(status_created_at) status_created_at
           FROM
               users_status
           GROUP BY user_id) m
           JOIN
               user_status s USING (user_id, status_created_at)
           ) c
 SET users.status = c.status
 WHERE users.id = c.user_id
```

Comment: You might consider using an AFTER INSERT trigger

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we want to update only those records which contain multiple entry for same user_id and user_status
Try below:

```
     update Users X ,
    (select a.user_id,a.user_status from (select user_id,user_status from users_status 
group by user_id,user_status having count(*)>1) a 
    inner join 
    (select user_id,user_status from 
    (select user_id,user_status from users_statys
order by status_created_at desc)temp 
group by user_id,user_status)b 
    on 
    a.user_id = b.user_id and a.user_status  = b.user_status) Y ,

 set X.status = Y.user_status where  X.id = Y.user_id;
```

Excuse typo:

if you can add data in sqlfiddle then I can check there

Comment: Don't you have a return key on your keyboard?

Comment: @Gery, Aah.. sorry you are right..  I just write query fast and post it.. let me format it. thanks for suggestion